# Имеет ли смысл в учебных вопросах отвечать на другом языке программирования?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы

Часто задают явно учебные вопросы - т.е. человек где-то учится и делает задания. Чтобы не навредить учебному процессу надо или закрывать вопрос через жалобы (если вопрос не содержит попытки решить), либо намекать ход решения (особено когда вопрос в алгоритме). Что если отвечать на другом языке программирования, возможно более "человекочитаемом"?  Например. почти все в школе проходят Паскаль - а вопрос про реализацию алгоритма на Java или C++. Стоит ли отвечать в виде программы на Паскале в данном случае? Чтобы с одной стороны подсказать, с другой дать человек самому написать программу?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нет прямого запрета писать в ответе код на языке, явно отличном от желаемого автором вопроса.

Можно, например, вообще на псевдокоде ответить, как на неком универсальном языке. Но бывают ситуации, когда пишут и явно на другом языке, т.к. отвечающий вроде как хочет помочь, но язык ТСа не знает. Это в какой-то мере напоминает мне ситуацию с ответом, написанном вовсе на отличном от русского языке.

И тут могут быть разные исходы:

- Если отвечающий решил достаточно сложную задачу в ответе, то такой ответ, даже несмотря на иной язык, может быть хорошо оценен сообществом;
- А если проблема тривиальна – результат может быть совсем противоположным (заминусуют).

В общем случае всё же стоит придерживаться языка, о котором идёт речь в вопросе. И эта рекомендация актуальна для любых вопросов, а не только учебного характера, заданного школьниками-студентами.

Comment: Формат вопросов и ответов подразумевает, что ответ решает описанную в вопросе проблему. Вся фишка Stack Overflow в том, что вопрос — ключ к знаниям в ответах. «Нет прямого запрета писать в ответе код на языке, явно отличном от желаемого автором вопроса.» — это как написать одно содержание книги, а содержимое той же книги совсем о другом или на другом языке. Нет никакой нужны писать подобное в правилах. Это вопрос здравого смысла. В остальном согласен. Псевдокод вполне допустим.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Совершенно не важно, кто что считает очевидным для здравого смысла. Либо мы говорим о фактах, либо о своём восприятии. Я говорю о фактах — прямого запрета нет. По поводу различных языков: в каких-нибудь учебниках по языкам человеческого общения, имхо, вполне можно встретить контент, написанный на другом языке, нежели оглавление. Если воспринимать SO как учебник, такой подход тоже можно попробовать наложить, но это довольно частный случай.

Comment: Подобное встречается в вопросе о переводе с одного языка на другой! В художественной литературе такого нет, либо сделано в такой малой пропорции и с конкретной целью подчеркнуть что–то. Аналог, например — показать реализацию шаблона одиночка в Python, рассказав откуда растут ноги, упомянув С++. Этот случай совершенно не о том, чтобы публиковать ответы на другом языке программирования, нежели указано в вопросе.

Comment: я как-то ответил на вопрос, использую псевдокласс `Month`,(вопрос был про сортировку месяцев), там мне кинули 2 минуса

Comment: @michael_best от минусов никто не застрахован.

Answer (score 9):

Если в вопросе есть метка [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc), то ответ можно давать на любом языке. В принципе, можно эту логику расширить на другие независящие от языка метки. Лично я бы ещё объединил в кучку все языки платформы .net, но с этим [не все согласны](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584116/178988).

А если явно требуется какая-то элементарная штука на конкретном языке, то давать её на другом как минимум странно.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите намекнуть человеку, как решить задачу, дайте алгоритм!
А дальше все уже зависит от того, как человек располагает знанием синтаксиса/умением искать информацию.

Answer (score 0):

#### Стоит давать такой ответ, который максимально точно отвечает на вопрос  в виде, который максимально легко использовать повторно.

Если в вопросе идет речь про алгоритм на C++, следует отвечать именно про этот алгоритм, именно на C++!  Думаете не стоит? Подумайте, как бы вы сами были обескуражены, если бы из поиска попадали на нужный вам вопрос на Stack Overflow, а ответ был на другом языке и не по теме...

---

Этот ответ приходит на ум сразу же, если взглянуть на [ключевые ценности сообщества](/help/key-values)

> Stack Overflow — это библиотека готовых решений прикладных задач, собранных в формате проблема (вопрос) — решения (ответы) в сжатом виде без ненужных деталей. Только «сигнал», никакого «шума».

Или [миссию](/help/manifesto)

> Общими силами создать библиотеку подробных ответов на все прикладные вопросы по программированию.

Совершенно не важно учебный это вопрос или вопрос по коммерческому проекту. Мы создаем [базу знаний по программированию](/help/key-values).

> Наличие полезных для сообщества знаний на сайте — важно, то как они были созданы — вторично. Мы приветствуем любые способы создания полезных знаний на сайте, кроме плагиата.

Мы пишем наши ответы не столько для автора вопроса, сколько для коллег, которые столкнутся с подобной задачей в будущем и попадут на Stack Overflow из поиска. Вопрос — ключ к знаниям в ответах. Пожалуйста, пишите максимально соответствующие вопросу ответы, которые раскрывают *всю* суть необходимого на ваш взгляд решения. Пишите их такими, какими бы вы хотели видеть решения, если бы сами искали информацию по этому вопросу.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как по вашему мнению нужно действовать участнику/модератору, если он видит ответ с реализацией на языке, отличном от запрашиваемого ТС (явно, или косвенно на основании меток).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Я бы написал участнику в комментариях, что именно следует исправить в его ответе, чтобы он помогал другим людям.

Comment: ну, допустим, написали, а он проигнорировал, что дальше?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ минус ответу, так как "ответ не является полезным".

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev мне бы хотелось услышать автора ответа.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ модераторы тревоги будут отклонять, скорей всего, как "не следует использовать тревогу на неверном ответе")